# How to implement Cloneable class?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

```
class Cloneable
{
 public:
   virtual Cloneable* clone() const = 0; //return copy of itself
   virtual ~Cloneable() {}
};

class A
{
 public:
   A(const A& a);    
   ~A();  

 private:
   Cloneable* b;
   Cloneable* c;
   std::string* s;     
};

A::~A()  
{
 delete b;
 delete c;
 delete s;
}
```

Please, help me to understand cloneable pattern. I don't understand how to implement constructor, copy constructor of class A and how can I use it?

Comment: I disagree with this being marked as too broad, or "a good answer would be too long". The question makes sense and user3684240 gives a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first of all need to distinguish between the copy constructor and the clone pattern.

A **copy constructor** is a constructor that creates a copy of a class.

```
MyClass a;
MyClass copy(a); // calls the copy constructor
```

You (usually) don't need to implement it yourself, the compiler will create a so-called *implicit copy constructor* for you. If you however need to implement (e.g. because you write a class that manages a resource), please consider the rule of five ([Rule-of-Three becomes Rule-of-Five with C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11)).

A copy constructor is not virtual (in fact, constructors are never virtual).

A typical use case for the clone pattern is this:

```
#include <memory>
class MyAbstractClass {
  virtual void someFunction();
};
class MyHeir : public MyAbstractClass {
  virtual void someFunction() override { /* TODO */ }
};
class MyHeir2 : public MyAbstractClass {
  virtual void someFunction() override { /* TODO */ }
};
std::unique_ptr<MyAbstractClass> ptr1 = std::make_unique<MyHeir>();
std::unique_ptr<MyHeir> clone; // TODO: clone
```

There is no way for the compiler to know at compile time whether `ptr1` contains an instance of `MyHeir` or of `MyHeir2`. That's why you need the clone pattern. You basically just implement a virtual function that copies the class (read: calls the copy constructor).

```
// in MyAbstractClass
virtual MyAbstractClass* clone() = 0;
// in MyHeir
virtual MyHeir * /* return type covariance */ clone() {
  return new MyHeir(*this); // call to the (implicit) copy constructor
}
// in MyHeir2
virtual MyHeir2 * /* return type covariance */ clone() {
  return new MyHeir2(*this);
}
```

Now you can do:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyHeir> clone = ptr1->clone();
```